# Поиск минимального значения суммы последовательности по условию (доказательство)

Tags: математика

> **Задача**: найдите минимальное N такое, что если из чисел 1,2,3...,N убрать любые 1000 чисел, то из оставшихся можно выбрать ровно 1000 чисел с суммой N.

Сначала хотела написать код, чтобы получить ответ, но поняла, что не представляю, как он должен выглядеть в данной ситуации.

Вручную сделала грубую оценку, получила что это число должно быть чуть больше миллиона, но не знаю, какое это число и не знаю, как доказать, что оно наименьшее.

Comment: Не понимаю закрывающих... 3 голоса за "надо конкретизировать". Что вам непонятно? Задача-то интересная, обидно будет, если вопрос будет закрыт... Кстати, мне кажется, что ответ 1500500, но вот как это *доказать*?

Comment: Грубая оценка всё же больше полутора миллионов. Сумма чисел от 1001 до 2000.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Она и есть 1500500. И ощущение, что она и есть ответ. Нет?

Comment: Да, похоже. Но строгое доказательство пока не сочиняется

Comment: @AlexeyTen Отож... вроде какое число из этой суммы не вычеркни — а можно подобрать ему пару так, что эта же сумма получится другой парой... Но, увы, это так, рассуждения, но не строгое доказательство.

Comment: Да, задача из тех, что просто сформулировать, да хрен докажешь. Я тоже за 1500500, но вот как доказать... Может быть начать с суммы трёх или пяти чисел? Количество чисел 1000 не приципиально?

Comment: @Harry кажется придумал. Довольно просто :)

Comment: @Harry согласен, закрывать вопрос надо не как "необходимо конкретизировать", а как учебное задание

Comment: Либо я задачу не понял, либо все тупят, ведь сумма первых 1000 чисел равна 500500, зачем вам нужна сумма второй 1000, где сумма почти в три раза больше, чем ваше решение

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Очевидно, что требуемое `N` не меньше **1500500**. Т.к. это минимальная сумма 1000 чисел при вычёркивании 1000 чисел от 1 до 1000.

`1001 + 1002 + ... + 2000 = 1500500`.

Докажем что это требуемое число.
Разобьём первые 3000 чисел на пары:

- `1`, `3000`;
- `2`, `2999`;
- `3`, `2998`;
- …
- `1500`, `1501`.

Получим 1500 пар, причём сумма чисел в каждой из пар равна `3001`.
После вычёркивания 1000 чисел, у нас точно останется не менее 500 пар в которых оба числа не вычеркнуты. Сумма чисел этих 500 пар даст нам `3001 * 500 = 1500500`.

QED